# Metamask handling errors

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

This is my first time working on Ethereum and I'm having a few problems.

I have on my contract some require's, in order to validate some data from the sender. For example:

```
function bid() public payable {
     require(msg.value >= basePrice, "Amount must be greater than the base price.");
}
```

Testing this from a JavaScript frontend, I looking at the response I'm receiving in case of error and I'm finding it too difficult to parse the message

```
async function bid() {
    var accounts = await web3js.eth.getAccounts();
    auction.methods.bid()
        .send({ from: accounts[0], value: web3.toHex(web3.toWei($("#ethValue").val(), 'ether')) })
        .on("receipt", function(receipt) {
            console.log("Money sent!");
        })
        .on("error", function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        } 
}
```

This is what I'm getting at the error log

> Error: Returned error: Error: Error: [ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload {"id":2431858122425,"jsonrpc":"2.0","params":["0xf872118504a817c8008280b89494620ca9f4aef9b39edb3c1092269e03c64f98598810a741a462780000841998aeef822d46a0113065dec1772bb4ef374f2d9c76593278849bb70f8dd3b94ce8b728ec702c36a0157f5915c39695f653b92fa0b30966098baecdbd195b29e76e205d92554a6dff"],"method":"eth_sendRawTransaction"} Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert Amount must be greater than the minimal price.

Is there any way to keep only the message I sent from the contract?

Comment: which version of web3js are u using?

Comment: @Div I'm using 1.0.x